# Module loading with multiple processes

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, julia

I'm puzzled by Julia behavior around loading modules when worker processes are used.

I need to use a rather heavy `PyPlot` module which takes a considerable amount of time to load. This program:

```
using PyPlot
pygui(true)
println("Loaded")
```

takes around 11 seconds to load on my laptop:

```
% time julia test.jl 
INFO: Loading help data...
Loaded
julia test.jl  11,10s user 0,18s system 99% cpu 11,323 total
```

Note the `INFO: Loading help data...` line. It seems to be emitted by the PyPlot module as it does not appear if I omit `using PyPlot` line.

However, when I run this program:

```
using PyPlot
pygui(true)
@everywhere println("Loaded")
```

I get these results:

```
% time julia -p 4 test.jl 
INFO: Loading help data...
INFO: Loading help data...
INFO: Loading help data...
INFO: Loading help data...
INFO: Loading help data...
Loaded
    From worker 2:  Loaded
    From worker 5:  Loaded
    From worker 3:  Loaded
    From worker 4:  Loaded
julia -p 4 test.jl  88,94s user 1,19s system 266% cpu 33,865 total
```

Not only it runs for whopping 33 seconds (three times longer!), but it also seems to load PyPlot module *on every worker*!

But I was sure that in order for module to be available on each worker, it has to be `@everywhere`d! Indeed, this simple program crashes:

```
module Example
    export x
    x = 10
end

using Example

@everywhere println("x: $x")
```

Invocation:

```
% julia -p 4 test2.jl
x: 10
exception on 2: exception on exception on exception on 4: 5: 3: ERROR: x not defined
 in eval at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/sys.so
ERROR: x not defined
 in eval at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/sys.so
ERROR: x not defined
 in eval at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/sys.so
ERROR: x not defined
 in eval at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/sys.so
```

So why is `PyPlot` module loaded on all workers even if I didn't request it?

What's even more interesting, there is a workaround:

```
using PyPlot
pygui(true)
addprocs(4)
@everywhere println("Loaded")
```

When I run this program with `julia test.jl`, I get 15 seconds:

```
% time julia test.jl     
INFO: Loading help data...
Loaded
    From worker 2:  Loaded
    From worker 4:  Loaded
    From worker 5:  Loaded
    From worker 3:  Loaded
julia test.jl  21,98s user 0,46s system 143% cpu 15,678 total
```

which is exactly what I'd have expected for the original version ran with `julia -p 4 test.jl`. But I don't like this workaround because it forces my program to use `addprocs()`.

Is there a way to restrict module loading to the master process when Julia is started with `-p X` argument?

Answer (score 2):

Let's test using `DummyModule.jl`:

```
module DummyModule

export MyType, f

type MyType
    a::Int
end

f(x) = x^2+1

println("loaded")

end
```

With this, we can see that there are actually 3 possibilities. All of these experiments are run from a fresh julia session invoked as `julia -p 2`.

#### Use DummyModule on all processes

```
julia> @everywhere using DummyModule
loaded
        From worker 3:  loaded
        From worker 2:  loaded

julia> @everywhere println(f(4))
17
        From worker 2:  17
        From worker 3:  17

julia> rr = RemoteRef(2)
RemoteRef(2,1,24)

julia> put!(rr, MyType(7))
RemoteRef(2,1,24)

julia> fetch(rr)
MyType(7)
```

#### Use DummyModule only on the driver process

```
julia> include("DummyModule.jl")
loaded

julia> using DummyModule

julia> @everywhere println(f(4))
exception on 2: 17
exception on 3: ERROR: f not defined
 in eval at /home/tim/src/julia/base/sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1383
 in anonymous at multi.jl:819
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:592
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:601
 in anonymous at task.jl:6
ERROR: f not defined
 in eval at /home/tim/src/julia/base/sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1383
 in anonymous at multi.jl:819
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:592
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:601
 in anonymous at task.jl:6

julia> rr = RemoteRef(2)
RemoteRef(2,1,14)

julia> put!(rr, MyType(7))
WARNING: Module DummyModule not defined on process 2
fatal error on 2: ERROR: DummyModule not defined
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:376
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:351
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:505
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:351
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:334
 in anonymous at serialize.jl:354
 in ntuple at tuple.jl:30
 in deserialize_tuple at serialize.jl:354
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:346
 in anonymous at task.jl:824
Worker 2 terminated.ERROR: ProcessExitedException()
 in wait at ./task.jl:284
 in wait at ./task.jl:194
 in wait_full at ./multi.jl:574
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:675
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:680
 in call_on_owner at multi.jl:722
 in put! at multi.jl:743
```

(Note the order in which different messages are printed is not deterministic; in `exception on 2: 17`, the `exception ...` part is due to an error being issued from process 2, and the `17` comes from printing `f(4)` on process 1.)

#### Using only on process 1, but passing data among workers

```
julia> using DummyModule
loaded
        From worker 3:  loaded
        From worker 2:  loaded

julia> @everywhere println(f(4))
exception on 2: 17
exception on 3: ERROR: f not defined
 in eval at /home/tim/src/julia/base/sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1383
 in anonymous at multi.jl:819
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:592
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:601
 in anonymous at task.jl:6
ERROR: f not defined
 in eval at /home/tim/src/julia/base/sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1383
 in anonymous at multi.jl:819
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:592
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:601
 in anonymous at task.jl:6

julia> rr = RemoteRef(2)
RemoteRef(2,1,19)

julia> put!(rr, MyType(7))
RemoteRef(2,1,19)

julia> using DummyModule

julia> fetch(rr)
MyType(7)
```

The distinction in the last case is that the serializer actually knows how to handle `MyType` on all processes, making it safe to pass data among workers.

Comment: Update: I improved the documentation in the manual, see http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#code-availability-and-loading-packages

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation, but I still don't understand why `using` a module only in the main process forces all of the workers to load this module. This seems counterintuitive and for large modules like `PyPlot` severely increases startup time.

Comment: Yes, this is counterintuitive and complicated. Are there many use cases for loading a module and not bringing it into scope?

Comment: `@everywhere` should be also used with `include("DummyModule.jl")` for the module to be visible to all processors.